# FileNotFoundException unreported

Tags: java, compiler-errors, filenotfoundexception

I'm running into an error of an unreported FileNotFoundException when trying to  instantiate an object with a file in my test code. The class that I'm using/created has the FileNotFoundException in the constructor (only one constructor) so I'm not quite sure why I'm being asked for an additional FileNotFound when declaring an object.

```
//Constructor 
    public readFile(File file)throws FileNotFoundException {
    //do i need to create a file object here?
            Scanner inScanFile = new Scanner(file);
        }

    ///////////Running Code from JUNIT below//////////////
        public void Empty(){
            File testFile = new File("HARRY_POTTER_TRIVIA.txt");
            ReadingClass newReadtest = new ReadingClass(testFile); //Error occurs here
```

Comment: Hmm... what part of "File Not Found" do you not understand?

Comment: `Scanner inScanFile = new Scanner(file);` is trying to find the file at the absolute path, but that file doesn't exist, so it throws an exception.

Comment: If there is a FileNotFoundException in the class, why am I getting an unreported exception to include an additional FileNotFoundException when I instantiate an object using that class.

Comment: just so everyone is clear, nothing is being thrown, i'm getting a compile error when i try to instantiate an object letting me know i need an additional FileNotFoundException

Comment: You have to give `Empty()` the same treatment you gave `readFile()` to make it compile. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: I understand I can make it compile if I add the throwsException to my test case but that seems unnecessary to have that much repetitive code. Why isn't that FileNotFoundException not sufficient? The parameter is being used only in that constructor.

Comment: It isn't unnecessary. Declaring `readFile()` to throw `FileNotFoundException` implies that people who call it have to handle it or throw it. That's the meaning of the syntax. Alternatively you can try/catch inside `Empty()`.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand you clearly,  if the file is being passed in the readFile() class, a single FileNotFoundException is sufficient. When a user calls it outside that class, another FileNotFoundException is needed?

Comment: You aren't making sense. `readFile()` executes code that can throw `FileNotFoundException`. So it has to either catch it or declare that it throws it. As you have declared that it throws it, now `Empty()` calls code that can throw it, so it too needs to either catch it or declare that it throws it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public readFile(File file)throws FileNotFoundException {
//do i need to create a file object here?
```

No, why? You already have one.

```
        Scanner inScanFile = new Scanner(file);
```

This can throw `FileNotFoundException`, which is why this constructor has to either catch it or declare that it throws it, or one of its base classes.

```
    }

///////////Running Code from JUNIT below//////////////
    public void Empty(){
        File testFile = new File("HARRY_POTTER_TRIVIA.txt");
        ReadingClass newReadtest = new ReadingClass(testFile); //Error occurs here
```

That's because `readFile()` can throw `FileNotFoundException`, so, again, you have to either catch it or declare that you throw it, or one of its  base classes.

Comment: This makes more sense but I dont see how the readFile() can throw an exception that wouldn't be caught by the constructor. If you create a file object to file that doesn't exist...java still compiles.